# Открытие в браузере ответа от cURL (php)

Tags: javascript, php, curl

В наличии: браузер с js, сервер с php и cURL.

**Цель**: отправить данные на другой сайт (Яндекс.Деньги) с помощью php и показать страницу с его ответом в браузере.

**Проблемы**:

1. нельзя использовать ajax в js (Access-Control-Allow-Origin).
2. нельзя использовать file_get_contents в php (allow_url_fopen=0).

**Сейчас**:

1. Отправляю данные POST запросом через ajax на мой сервер.
2. Мой сервер данные проверяет, творит магию.
3. Мой сервер отправляет данные в Яндекс, используя cURL.
4. Мой сервер отдаёт в браузер ответ от другого сайта.

**Вопрос:**
**Как отобразить ответ другого сервера заместо той страницы, которую сейчас показывает браузер?**

Если использовать echo, то я получаю строку, которую в js могу показать где угодно в отображаемой странице. Но это не то, чего нужно добиться, ведь ответ другого сервера - html со своими натюрмортом. Должно получиться как будто я выполнил window.open с "_blank" (но она не поддерживает POST).

Часть кода:

```
$request_headers = array();
$request_headers[] = 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

$post_data = json_encode($values);
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);    

echo $html;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исключите из вашей схемы AJAX и всё заработает. Если нужен POST-запрос используйте форму, отправить её можно и js'ом (`form.submit()`).

Обратите внимание, что тело HTTP-ответа это ещё не весь "натюморт" (есть ещё заголовки, например куки).

А вообще у Яндекс.Денег есть [API](https://money.yandex.ru/doc.xml?id=525037) для интеграции (думаю, это как раз то что вы хотите сделать).

Answer (score 0):

Как мне кажется, ответ на Ваш вопрос:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109205/open-window-in-javascript-with-html-inserted

```
var win = window.open("", "Title", "toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=780,height=200,top="+(screen.height-400)+",left="+(screen.width-840));
win.document.body.innerHTML = "HTML";
```